# Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^x xf(t)dt$.

Tags: calculus

> Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^x xf(t)dt$.

I tried performing integration by parts to get $\displaystyle F(x) = xtf(t)-\int f'(t)f(x)xt dt$, but I am not sure how that helps. Also, are we assuming $x(f(t))$ to be integrable because otherwise the integral doesn't exist?

(This problem appears in Calculus by Michael Spivak, 3rd Ed., Chapter 14, Problem 11.)

Comment: You can write $F(x) = x\int_0^xf(t)dt$ and then just use the product rule. Presumably $x$ is not a function of $t$ and thus you can pull it out of the integral.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $x$ is a constant with respect to the variable of integration, so
$$\int_{0}^{x}xf(t)\text{ d}t = x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t\text{.}$$
Notice that $F$ is a product of two functions of $x$: $x$, and $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t$. So, we need to use the product rule.
$$F^{\prime}(x) =(x)^{\prime} \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t+x\left[\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t \right]^{\prime} = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t+xf(x)\text{.}$$
Note that I used the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) for computing $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t$. One of the assumptions here, as you can see, is that $f$ needs to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$F(x) = x \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$$ and use the product rule: $$F'(x) = x f(x) + \int_0^x f(t) \, dt.$$

Comment: What if $f(t)$ is not integrable with respect to $t$?

Comment: Then the function $F$ is not defined and hence not differentiable.

Comment: So this is under the assumption $f(t)$ is integrable with respect to $t$.

Comment: Of course it is.